# Then function isn't called after returning a promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I created a function to check if an element already exist, if not repeat the function until it does:

```
function waitForElementToDisplay(selector) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (document.querySelector(selector) != null) {
            console.log('Element is displayed now');
            resolve();
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                waitForElementToDisplay(selector, 500);
            }, 500);
        }
    })
}
```

I use this function in the `beforeShowPromise` function of Shepherd.js. This function let the package wait with going to the next tour step until the promise is resolved. The `beforeShowPromise` function looks like this:

```
beforeShowPromise: function () {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve) {

        const selector = '.exampleTemplates';

        await waitForElementToDisplay(selector).then(() => {
            console.log('Do something');
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    })
},
```

I want to wait until the `waitForElementToDisplay` function is resolved, so the function of Shepherd can be resolved. However, the `.then` nor the `.catch` functions are being called. Can someone explain to me why it isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass along the `resolve` to the recursive call:

```
const checkIfElementExists = (resolve, selector) => {
  if (document.querySelector(selector) !== null) {
    console.log('Element is displayed now');
    resolve();
  } else {
    setTimeout(checkIfElementExists, 500, resolve, selector);
  }
};

function waitForElementToDisplay(selector) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    checkIfElementExists(resolve, selector);
  })
}
```

Or, encapsulated inside `waitForElementToDisplay`:

```
function waitForElementToDisplay(selector) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    (function checkIfElementExists() {
      if (document.querySelector(selector) !== null) {
        console.log('Element is displayed now');
        resolve();
      } else {
        setTimeout(checkIfElementExists, 500);
      }
    })();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Promise only resolves if the element exists.

If it doesn't, you hit the else branch which calls the function recursively. This creates a **new** promise, but you never do anything when *that* resolves. The original promise is left sitting in limbo.

You can resolve the original promise with the new promise:

```
resolve( waitForElementToDisplay(selector) );
```